# Firestorage has different behavior when hardcode

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I don't know what happened with my code. But everytime i used this code is working

```
const downloadUrlThumb = async(urlPathThumbs) => {
        const gsRef = projectStorage.refFromURL('gs://myapps.appspot.com/courses/m9APF8TEUnfS6IQew591sl4kphH2/thumbs/business-3560917_640_200x200.jpg') // hardcode mode
        //const gsRef = projectStorage.refFromURL(urlPathThumbs)
        await gsRef.getDownloadURL().then(urlDownload => {
            
            console.log('URL THUMB ADALAH: ', urlDownload);
            url.value = urlDownload

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    }
```

But when i switched to `urlPathThumbs` it will become error 404. Error said like so

> Firebase Storage: Object
> 'courses/m9APF8TEUnfS6IQew591sl4kphH2/thumbs/Rectangle 68
> (1)_200x200.png' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

however they both are same pattern. This is how variable `urlPathThumbs` created in previous snippet code

```
var filename = file.name.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '_200x200$1')
            console.log('filename ', filename);
            let location = 'gs://myapps.appspot.com/courses/'+user.value.uid+'/thumbs/'+filename
            console.log('full location: ', location); // --> This will print full location:  gs://myapps.appspot.com/courses/m9APF8TEUnfS6IQew591sl4kphH2/thumbs/Rectangle 68 (1)_200x200.png
            await downloadUrlThumb(location)
```

this file is successful uploaded and i can see it in firebase storage location:
[image: firebase storage]

Please can somebody help me?

Comment: Could it be because of the space?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial no, because image successful uploaded and when i checked in firebase storage its location is same. gs://myapps.appspot.com/courses/m9APF8TEUnfS6IQew591sl4kphH2/thumbs/Rectangle 68 (1)_200x200.png

Comment: you hardcode with the url from the 2nd example it work too? with the space?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yes, when i tried url contains space with hardcode it worked too

Comment: Are you making sure that your file was uploaded completely **before** you try to get the download URL?

Comment: @samthecodingman i don't know, after several attempt it works now. but in my first reload there was no effect. But now everthing is fine

Comment: If you can include the code where you are uploading the original file and where you get `file` from, we might be able to pinpoint the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since refFromURL is expecting a URL string, spaces should not be allow. You will need to urlencode the spaces.

e.g.

```js
console.log(encodeURI("gs://myapps.appspot.com/courses/m9APF8TEUnfS6IQew591sl4kphH2/thumbs/Rectangle 68 (1)_200x200.png"))
```

> refFromURL refFromURL ( url :  string ) : Reference Returns a
> reference for the given absolute URL.
>
> Parameters url: string A URL in the form: 1) a gs:// URL, for example
> gs://bucket/files/image.png 2) a download URL taken from object
> metadata. @see firebase.storage.FullMetadata.downloadURLs

Comment: Only inserted values should be processed by encodeURIComponent, not the whole URL.
Your code will return something like "gs%3A%2F%2Fmyapps.appspot.com%2Fcourses%2F..."

Comment: i use this `const gsRef = projectStorage.refFromURL(encodeURI(urlPathThumbs))` but still result 404. it was print nice path `gs://myapps.appspot.com/courses/m9APF8TEUnfS6IQew591sl4kphH2/thumbs/meeting-2284501_640_200x200.jpg` but still failed

Comment: Firebase Storage: Object 'courses/m9APF8TEUnfS6IQew591sl4kphH2/thumbs/meeting-2284501_640_200x200.jpg' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found). this is the error. does the error seems missed bucket path??

Comment: Don't forget about encodeURIComponent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent